# Aligning content in menu according to grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm using CSS Grid and I'm trying to position menu items within the second column of a grid. I have something like this:

```css
header {
    grid-area: header;
}
footer {
    grid-area: footer;
}
nav{
    grid-area:nav;
}

main {
    grid-area: main;
}

aside {
    grid-area: aside;
}

/* Resets */
:root {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: normal;
}

body {
      display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:[first] 1rem [sidebar] fit-content(10%) [content] auto;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header" "nav nav nav" ". aside main" "footer footer footer";
}

header {
  background-color: blue;
}

nav {
  background-color: red;
}

aside {
  height: fit-content;
  margin: 1rem 0 0 0;
}

main {
  background-color: orange;
}

footer {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <aside><div>Aside content</div></aside>
  <main><div>Main content here</div></main>
  <footer>
    <div>Footer content</div>
    <footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Basically, I want the list in the nav bar to align with the content in the `<main>` element; I've read through the CSS tricks guide and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:**

Adding `margin-left` on the `ul` element.

```
margin-left: 7rem;
padding: 0;
list-style-position: inside;
```

---

**Old answer:**

The following changes to your CSS are needed.

> You want to add in the two dots to space the nav area.

```
grid-template-areas: "header header header" ". . nav" ". aside main" "footer footer footer";
```

> The following will align the aside to the top-most row.

```
aside {grid-row-start: 2;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no luck, unfortunately! I still want the nav to extend across all three columns, but I want the ul inside the nav to be in the third column. In other words, I want the aside where it is still, and the red background to be the full width, but the list items to start where the main starts.

Comment: Ok, you could just add `margin-left` on the `ul`
`margin-left: 7rem; padding: 0; list-style-position: inside;`